# Show toolbars the "Add-ons Manager" tab is open

Tags: firefox

Can the behavior removing the toolbar from the add-ons tab be changed via a tweak or add-on so that the toolbar is still shown.  I frequently re-use my tabs and it is annoying that for this one I close the tab and open a new one rather than typing in a new address or clicking the home button.

This behavior has not changed from version 4 through 11.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking the blank space around the tabs and clicking customize. Here you can move things around and drag things off of there. I am not sure exactly what you are talking about because I have mine completely customized and it stayed that way when I upgraded. I hope this helps. If it does, tell me and I will make is a legit answer.

Comment: It seems to only behave this way when you have "Tabs on Top" turned on and only when you open the add-ons tab.  Right clicking and selecting customize shows that the toolbars are turned on and they do show for every other tab.  I believe this was an intentional change I just don't like it.

Comment: In that case, I would uninstall Firefox and reinstall the previous version (which is 3.6.16). You can download any version at [filehippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com/download_firefox/).

Comment: I don't dislike this minor annoyance any where near that much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

#main-window[disablechrome] #navigator-toolbox[tabsontop="true"] > 
toolbar:not(#toolbar-menubar):not(#TabsToolbar):not([collapsed="true"]) {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

in Stylish.

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Going to `about:addons` (the default behavior) opens up the **Add-ons Manager** with the Navigation toolbar hidden. However, there is an alternative Chrome URL for this page:

```
chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul?type=extensions
```

Note: `?type=extensions` may or may not be required, depending on the version of Firefox.

Using this address **does not** hide the Navigation toolbar.

[image: Add-ons Manager]

Comment: This comes extremely close to accomplishing my goal. +1  I used Custom Buttons to create a button to go directly to this URL, so now all I have to do is re-train myself to use it to get to the Add-ons Manager.  I'll hold out for a bit in case a better answer comes before accepting this one.

Answer (score 1):

There are [Add-ons Manager Dialog Returns](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-ons-manager-dialog-for-ff4/) and [Classicish Add-on Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicish-addon-manager/) add-ons. Both open Add-ons Manager in separate window (Classicish can be set to open in tab) and it can be closed with <kbd>Esc</kbd>. *Add-ons Manager Dialog Returns* arguably has several advantages in that it doesn't need restart, doesn't change the appearance of Add-ons Manager from the current one (although that could very well be a bonus for *Classicish*, depending on personal preference) and it introduces a number of useful keyboard shortcuts (see AMO page for more info).

But you could also partially (in that it requires using a keyboard) get desired behavior without installing any add-on. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when in Add-ons Manager and Open Location dialog will pop up, so you can just type address, being offered suggestions same as in Location Bar, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click Open. It will open new address in current tab, replacing Add-ons Manager, by default. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open your default search engine - first in the Search Bar list, not currently selected. There is also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for Home Page.

Take your pick.

EDIT: [**Hide Navigation Bar**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/) add-on resolves it completely. It toggles Navigation Bar with <kbd>F2</kbd> (changeable) by default, so all you have to do is open Add-ons Manager and make it visible.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer.  It comes close in some ways to resolving the issue, so +1.  Unfortunately it does not actually achieve the desired effect of showing the toolbar on the Add-On tab.

Comment: See edit for complete solution.

Comment: Hide Navigation Bar is navigation bar specific.  I have several tool bars and have arranged the widgets such that the address portion is not on the "Navigation Bar".  Going to the Add-ons Manager page removes all the other toolbars leaving only the "Navigation Bar".  The extension then allows me to hide and reveal this one remaining toolbar, but does nothing for all the others.  Thank you for you efforts though.